# Getting GRUB to show all my OSes at once

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows

Initially scared the wits out of myself, because despite my semi-thorough but still slightly hasty attempts to research the correct way to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS as a third boot option alongside Windows 10 and 8, I could only see Ubuntu and "Windows 8 (Boot Loader)" as options in GRUB. I took that to mean my attempt to manually resize the partition with Windows 10 on it and install Ubuntu there back-fired and tanked my install of Windows 10.

However I came to appreciate what the 'Boot Loader' in parenthesis meant, when on a whim I went to check if selecting what I thought would load Windows 8 correctly and shutting down from there would enable me to access Windows 10. I didn't anticipate it'd launch Windows Boot Loader with options for Windows 10 and 8 there. Successfully booted 10 and disabled the Quick Boot option as I read I should to make GRUB work better, alas it had the same options when I rebooted and my PC came up with GRUB first.

This is certainly serviceable as it is, I can run all my OSes with only an extra selection involved, but I'm inexperienced with Linux and GRUB, so **I thought I'd ask if I could get the options of booting directly into Ubuntu, Windows 10, and Windows 8 to show in GRUB and bypass the Windows Boot Loader entirely by doing some extra configuration?** Perhaps I did mess up a step somewhere, or missed one entirely, or this is all normal and I just need to invest a little more work. However my current searches proved unfruitful so I thought I'd put it out to the experts!

Thanks preemptively for your time and patience reading.

Comment: Try running `sudo grub-install /dev/sda; sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu Boot Repair should be able to do that for you. You'll need to boot into a Live session and then follow these instructions:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Thanks, not able to do that at this moment, but I'm satisfied with knowing it sounds plausible to somebody.